# Как сделать что бы круг анимационно падал в низ к блоку? и так же потом на верх подымался

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, html5

```
<div class="menu-list">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <span class="circle-list-menu-hover"></span>
                  <span class="circle-dropdown"></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 change-block-for-fixed-top">
                                        <div class="change hover-element">
                                            <div class="change-blur" data-hover-background="black"></div>
                                            <p data-hover-color="#F88360" data-color="#FBFCFD">Обменять</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <span class="circle-list-menu-hover"></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="resrv hover-element">
                                            <div class="change-blur" data-hover-background="black"></div>
                                            <p data-hover-color="#F88360" data-color="#FBFCFD">Курс/Резерв</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <span class="circle-list-menu-hover"></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="salle hover-element">
                                            <div class="change-blur" data-hover-background="black"></div>
                                            <p data-hover-color="#F88360" data-color="#FBFCFD">Скидки</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <span class="circle-list-menu-hover"></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="faq hover-element">
                                            <div class="change-blur" data-hover-background="black"></div>
                                            <p data-hover-color="#F88360" data-color="#FBFCFD">Faq</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <span class="circle-list-menu-hover"></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="partners hover-element">
                                            <div class="change-blur" data-hover-background="black"></div>
                                            <p data-hover-color="#F88360" data-color="#FBFCFD">Партнерам</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <span class="circle-list-menu-hover"></span>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 change-block-for-fixed-bottom">
                                        <div class="applications hover-element">
                                            <div class="change-blur" data-hover-background="black"></div>
                                            <p data-hover-color="#F88360" data-color="#FBFCFD">Заявки</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>




html{
  background:red;
}
.menu-list{
    border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
  background: red;
    .change-block-for-fixed-top{
        position: absolute;
        top: -11px;
    }
    .change-block-for-fixed-bottom{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -21px;
    }
    .row:nth-child(1){
        padding: 0 0 80px 40px;
        .circle-list-menu-hover{
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: 7px;
            height: 7px;
            background: #fff;
            left: 11px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            top: 0;
        }
    .circle-dropdown{
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            position: absolute;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            border-radius: 50%;
            left: 0;
            top: -11px;
        }
    }
    .row:last-child{
        padding: 0 0 0 40px;
        .circle-list-menu-hover{
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: 7px;
            height: 7px;
            background: #fff;
            left: 11px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            top: -5px;
        }
    }
    .row{
        padding: 0 0 55px 40px;
        font-family: Akrobat-Bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #FBFCFD;
        letter-spacing: 1.24px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        position: relative;
        .circle-list-menu-hover{
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            width: 7px;
            height: 7px;
            background: #fff;
            left: 11px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            top: 11px;
        }
    }
    .change, .resrv, .salle, .faq, .partners, .applications{
        position: relative;
        .change-blur{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 30px;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 30px;
            left: -9px;
        }
        .change-blur:hover{
            background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255, 129, 65, 0.19), rgba(255, 183, 117, 0));
            -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
            -moz-filter: blur(5px);
            -o-filter: blur(5px);
            -ms-filter: blur(5px);
            filter: blur(5px);
        }
    }

}
```

https://codepen.io/Akilian/pen/PdRrQJ

нужно что бы круг падал ниже при нажатие на меню и подымался на верх при нажатии на верхнее меню)

вообще не шарю как оформить это

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
         let $menu = $('.hover-element');
         let $circle = $('.circle-dropdown');
         $('.hover-element').click(function() {
            let $y = $(this).offset().top;
            console.log($y)
            $circle.animate({
                    top: $y
            }, 200);
          });
 });
```

Comment: анимация есть) но она падает тупо в низ) а не нажатие на курс резервов кружок должен быть вокруг круга Курс/Резервов) а у вас он в низ тупо уезжает

Comment: кружок падает, туда куда кликнули из пунктов меню и обрачивает маленький кружок, все работает как нужно

Comment: хм, у меня падает просто в низ)

Comment: можете функцию написать на jquery или же на javascripte  у меня ошибки выдают на $menu

Comment: ну вот 
http://prntscr.com/ktgppd
жму на курс и вон где кружок)

Comment: вы структуру верстки не меняли?

Comment: нет структуру верстки не менял

Comment: смотри я закинул свой код в codePen, который ты скинул и все работает хорошо

Comment: у меня там не работает) я не знаю)) вообщем) сложно) буду розбираться) спасибо за помощь)

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    var circle = $('.hover-element');
    var state = $('.circle-dropdown');
    $('.hover-element').click(function() {
       var y = $(this).offset().top;
       console.log(y)
       state.animate({
               top: y
       }, 200);
     });
});

я вот так переделал

Comment: я пересохранил на codepan можете зайти посмотреть там тоже не работает)

Comment: во-первых ты там не подключил jquery, во-вторых ты поменял мой код и он перестал работать, ты поменял там название переменных и он не находит их

Comment: у меня в проекте let , $menu не поддерживает такого правописания кода) 

var menu = так не работает(

Comment: подключи jquery и вставь туда -  $(document).ready(function() {
         var menu = $('.hover-element');
         var circle = $('.circle-dropdown');
         $('.hover-element').click(function() {
            var y = $(this).offset().top;
            console.log(y)
            circle.animate({
                    top: y
            }, 200);
          });
 });

Comment: на кодепене все хорошо) у меня в проекте все плохо))) это фиаско

Comment: там скорее всего верстку надо править, код рабочий

Comment: верстка взяти з проекта